# Permissions problem after SP1 on SharePoint Server

Tags: sharepoint

> You do not have permissions to do this
>   operation. Ask your website
>   administrator to change your
>   pemissions and then try again, or log
>   on with another account that has this
>   permission. To log on with another
>   user account click ok.

I need some help regarding the above error. After applying SP1 pack on our SharePoint Server 2007 (MOSS 3.0) the workflows aren't working anymmore on one of the WebApplications (located in SSP2) Workflows work, however on other existing applications (on SSP1 or SSP2) or newly created applications (on SSP1 or SSP2).

Details of error: 1. Default / Built in SharePoint Workflows are not starting 2. Sharepoint Designer Workflows throwing the following error message: "You do not have permissions to do this operation. Ask your website administrator to change your pemissions and then try again, or log on with another account that has this permission. To log on with another user account click ok. " 3. Before applying the SP1 on MOSS the workflows were working perfectly fine on this WebApplication.

so far: 1. I am logged in as Administrator (bot on Sharepoint site or when working with Sharepoint Designer). 2. Administrator is included in the list Site Collection Administrators 3. I noticed in Sharepoint designer that the username used for creating the workflow is 'converted' into SHAREPOINT\system (in the Modified By Column).

Has anybody come accross/fixed this error?

Any help much appreciated. Thanks D

Comment: This sounds like a question for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to [Disable the Loop Back check](http://blogs.bluethreadinc.com/thellebuyck/archive/2008/10/30/401.1-error-when-accessing-sharepoint-from-server.aspx), this is something introduced in SP1 to avoid running things as the System Account for security purposes.

> 1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
> 2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
> 3. Right-click Lsa, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
> 4. Type DisableLoopbackCheck, and then press ENTER.
> 5. Right-click DisableLoopbackCheck, and then click Modify.
> 6. In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.

Please understand that this feature exists for a reason, and you should configure your accounts properly to avoid the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have changed registry as suggested, but I still have the same problem. Although start manual workflow can be created in Sharepoint Designer, it will not start when triggered manually in the list. 
Creating automatic workflows in Sharepoint Designer will generate the same error: "You do not have permissions to do this operation. Ask your website administrator to change your pemissions and then try again, or log on with another account that has this permission. To log on with another user account click ok"
Thanks, 
D

Comment: Keep in mind that after SP1 you cannot run workflows with the System Account, try logging in with another account. See if that helps